# Inflating ListView, the second time it becomes transparent

Tags: android, listview, transparency

In the Main Layout I have a ViewFlipper with two ListView inside, follows an excerpt.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/chinese_background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
[...]
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/vFlipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textStatus"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSearch" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstVocab01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstVocab02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
[...]
```

I inflate the **same** item layout inside both the ListView exploiting the **same** CursorAdapter (I am retrieving data from a database). Follows the item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLine01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_big" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLine02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_normal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As in the Main Layout, there is nothing that change styles or anything related. The adapter does nothing except inflating the DB fields inside the proper TextViews.

There is no difference in the way I update the two cursors. Given `CursorAdapterVocabulary adapter_c;` and `CursorAdapterVocabulary adapter_e;` correctly instantiated and correctly working.

```
adapter_c.changeCursor(cursor);
adapter_c.notifyDataSetChanged();
if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1) {
    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_left);
    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_right);
    viewFlipper.showPrevious();
}
```

[...]

```
adapter_e.changeCursor(cursor);
adapter_e.notifyDataSetChanged();
if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0) {
    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_right);
    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_left);
    viewFlipper.showNext();
}
```

But: the first ListView is well visibile. The second view has a sort of alpha transparency, which I couldn't remove even forcing alpha to 1.

Please not that:

- The rest of the code works perfectly, ListView are updated every time with correct data
- It is not a problem of ViewFlipper, I used to have this problem also when I did the runtime replacing of the ListView
- I don't have this problem if I use the second ListView in another Activity
- The issue is Android Version/Device independent (tried on Samsung SPlus 2.3.6, SIII 4+, Emulator 4.3.0)

This is an image of the difference between the two views, I am filling them with data from a Chinese Vocabulary:

[image]

I don't know anymore what to try. Please ask me more details if needed.

Comment: Can you post here your anim XML files?

Comment: Of course. The 4 animation xml files are taken from this example (with no modifications): http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-viewflipper-example.html
But  want to higlight again that I had the same before implementing the ViewFLipper.